# How can I update the adapter in tablayout in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java, android-tablayout, swiperefreshlayout

Well I have a tablayout, inside the tablayout is 3 tabs(fragments) and inside of the fragment i need to update the whole tablayout using swiperefreshlayout. anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Why use a table layout? You can use a recycler view...

Comment: its tab layout bro

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent fragment which hold child fragments in a child fragment like this:

`private FragmentMain getMainFragment() {
        return (FragmentMain) getParentFragment(); }`

Then you can call a method from a child fragment to all other child fragments for overcome whatever task you want to accomplish.

```
 if((MainFragmentPagerAdapter) getMainFragment().viewPager.getAdapter().getItem(1) instanceof  ChildFragment1){
                                ((ChildFragment1) ((MainFragmentPagerAdapter)getMainFragment().viewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(1)).setTask();

                    } else if((MainFragmentPagerAdapter) getMainFragment().viewPager.getAdapter().getItem(2) instanceof  ChildFragment2){
                        ((ChildFragment2) ((MainFragmentPagerAdapter)getMainFragment().viewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(2)).setTask();
                    }
```